# HarmonyOS wearable JS scrollbars

Tags: huawei-developers, harmonyos

How to create scrollViews in harmonyOS? CSS/HTML/JS accepted, not java, because I develop on smart devices.

Android:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <!-- everything you already have -->

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Basically I want to create a parent scrollview and then put divs in that:

**[SCROLLVIEW_START]**

```
<slider value="7" max="10" min="0"
        style="background-color : transparent; width : 454px; height : 50px;"/>

<div for="{{ array }}" tid="id" onclick="changeText"
     style="background-color : #11efefef; align-items: center;
        border-color: black; border-width: 2px; height: 60px; width: 404px;">
    <text style="padding: 20px; color: white;">{{ $idx }}.{{ $item.name }}</text>
</div>
```

**[SCROLLVIEW_END]**

So how?

Answer (score 0):

The following are JS Components and Examples：

[scroll](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/ts-container-scroll-0000001163543527)

[div](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/js-components-container-div-0000000000611484)